# Contravariant Stress Tensor: expression derivation

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I was trying to go through a paper on relativistic, viscous radiation hydrodynamics, when I came upon this expression, for the contravariant stress tensor:

$T^{\alpha\beta}=\rho h u^\alpha u^\beta +P g^{\alpha\beta} - (Q_b/c^2) u^\alpha u^\beta -Q_b g^{\alpha\beta}-{Q_S}^{\alpha\beta}$

where,

$T^{\alpha\beta}$ is the contravariant stress tensor

$\rho $ density

$h=1+\epsilon/c^2+P/(\rho c^2)$  enthalpy

$u^\alpha$ contravariant four velocity

$P$ gas pressure

$e=\rho \epsilon$ internal energy density.

$Q_b$ the bulk (scalar) viscosity

${Q_S}^{\alpha\beta}$ the (symmetric) shear tensor viscosity

$g^{\alpha\beta}$ the curvature metric.

Can someone give me a reference on how such an expression is derived? I don't mind going through the math myself, but a reference would be really helpful.

Comment: What paper? Can you post a link to an online copy? Every paper should have a bibliography.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06423

Comment: This is the paper and the equation is the first one on it. Thank you for your reply